# How to run a Hybrid code of MPI and OpenMp on a cluster

Tags: c, parallel-processing, mpi, openmp

I have been working on Hybrid Parallelization of matrix multiplication code for my assignment. The purpose is to distribute the rows in nodes for Message Passing and within each node apply OpenMp to divide the rows further. Also we are trying to run on our college cluster which is each node having 16 core architecture and has 4 nodes. Now when the code is run it has to be such that there are 4 nodes and each has to spawn 4 OpenMP threads. But it is not running on 4 threads and during debugging we found each node runs the code only on 1 thread. We found this by looking at the CPU usage output by top command. When on one node, I run only the OpenMP code the CPU usage seems to be 400% meaning each thread runs in parallel and not concurrently. Coming to the mpi environment, I am using an Intel 64 architecture and the The mpirun command that I used to run the code is

```
**mpirun** -np 4 -machinefile ./machines hyb
```

where machines is a file which has details about the processors in the clusters. It is like this

```
gics1 slots=1
gics2 slots=1 
gics3 slots=1
gics4 slots=1
```

As an example code I have put another code and help regarding running it on cluster would be appreciated.

```
#include <mpi.h>
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    int world_rank, WORLD_SIZE;
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &WORLD_SIZE);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &world_rank);

    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
    int i;
    int a;
    for(i = 0; i < 10000000000; i++) {
        a = (a + 1)    % 100;
    }
        printf("MPI Rank: %d OMP Rank: %d\n", world_rank, 
            omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

The corresponding OpenMp code is

```
#include <omp.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

    omp_set_num_threads(4);
    #pragma omp parallel num_threads(4)
    {
    int i;
    int a;
    for(i = 0; i < 1000000000; i++) {
        a = (a + 1) % 100;
    }
        printf("OMP Rank: %d\n", omp_get_thread_num());
    }

    // MPI_Finalize();
    return 0;
}
```

The OpenMp code is running on 400% CPU utilization but not the Hybrid one.

Comment: Which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using ? What is your `mpirun` command line ? Do you use a resource manager (such as SLURM, PBSPro and friends ?) if yes, what is your job script ? Please edit your question with this critical information (e.g. do not post a comment)

Comment: I don't understand this statement "When on one node, I run only the OpenMP code the CPU usage seems to be 400% meaning each thread runs in parallel and not concurrently."

Comment: Can you provide the output from running the example code on four nodes?  I just ran your code on four nodes with four threads  per node and I get 4 MPI ranks and 4 OMP ranks per MPI rank for a total of 15 lines printed. Is this what you see?

Comment: @Zboson if the MPI job is not started correctly, the OpenMP threads might end up doing time sharing (hence a load average of 100% instead of 409%)

Comment: @GillesGouaillardet I have edited the question but I don't know what is the job script.

Comment: @Zboson Can you explain me how did you end up getting 15 line code because that would mean for each MPI node you are getting 4 OpenMp nodes.

Comment: Which MPI library (vendor and version) are you using ? if Open MPI, try to `mpirun --bind-to none ...`. Also run `mpirun -machinefile ./machinefile -np 4 grep Cpus_allowed_list /proc/self/status`

Comment: @hasnaingandhi, I ran on a cluster with many nodes. It has it's own batch submission system. But I also tested on my local machine with only 1 node using `mpirun -np ./a.out` and I got the same result (four processes, four threads per process for a total of 16 - 15 was a typo, I meant to write 16) . What hardware are you running on?  What output do you get when you do `mpirun -np 4 ./a.out`?